# How can I disable auto-updating of Market apps?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

Is there any way that to turn off auto update of Android Market apps? My phone prompts me for available updates and it runs in the background, and I think it's sapping precious battery power.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, change the notification settings in `Market -> (Menu button/Action Bar Button depending on device) Settings`.